# Error while selecting data from the search in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
  search:'',
 searchHistory: [],
  showSearchHistory: false,
  
  selectPreviousSearch(index) {
        this.search = this.searchHistory[index];
        this.showSearchHistory = false;
        
        
      },
```

```html
<input
          class="form-control"
          id="SearchText"
          type="text"
          v-model="search"
          @keydown.enter="enter"
          @click="onClick"
          @keyup.enter="processSearch"
          @input="change"
          @keyup="inputChanged"
          @keydown.down="onArrow"
          @keydown.up="onArrow"
          
        />


        <ul class="list-inline" >
          
          <li
            class="list-inline-item list-group-item-primary"
            v-for="(item, index) in searchHistory
              .slice(-5)
              .reverse()
              .map((s) => s.trim())"
            :key="index"
            @click="selectPreviousSearch(index)"
          >
            {{ item }}
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Above is logic for, if i add anything in search and click on search button, data will be reflected down in the list tag below.

Now the issue is, Onclick of "selectPreviousSearch"(i.e, data from li ) accurate data is not displaying in the search.

For example like, If i enter something in search i.e, a,b,c,d. Data is reflecting in Li, But when i click on a, "a" should display in search, But instead of "a" i am getting some different values in search.

Comment: why not just pass the item? `@click="selectPreviousSearch(item)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you are slicing the `searchHistory` array and getting only the last 5 elements, and you also reverse the array here:

```
        v-for="(item, index) in searchHistory
          .slice(-5)
          .reverse()
          .map((s) => s.trim())"
```

The `index` value on the loop will be the index on this new array, so when you do:

```
this.searchHistory[index];
```

It won't get the right one.

You can fix the logic there or do something like:

```
this.search = this.searchHistory.slice(-5).reverse()[index];
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by  @Lawrence Cherone in his response, you can just do:

```
@click="selectPreviousSearch(item)"
```

if you need the value of `this.search` to be trimmed, it will work just fine like that.

Comment: It's Working fine perfectly, But now the issue is if i click enter in search, space also reflecting in the li

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry,I mean  In the input field, if i Just press enter  button in the keyboard, space also reflecting in li.

Comment: You should use the solution in the comments. if you need to trim the value. @Lawrence Cherone

Comment: updated my answer there see if it helps. Because in case you need to trim the string it is better to jest pass the value full

Comment: I already i have  @click="onClick" in the input, So in that method i have   onClick() {
        
        this.showSearchHistory = true;
      },

Comment: I tried adding like this.selectPreviousSearch(item); in the onClick method. 

But it doesn't work

Comment: after doing this you need to change the method like this: `selectPreviousSearch(item) { this.search = item;...`